# Instantiate C# class in ASP.NET in page partial or within method

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I might not be explaining this clearly. But what are the drawbacks in creating the class inside the partial class vs. inside each method? (please see examples)

Example inside partial:

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{

cSystem oSystem = new cSystem();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    oSystem.useme();
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    oSystem.usethis();
}
```

versus

Example inside each class:

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    cSystem oSystem = new cSystem();
    oSystem.useme();
}
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    cSystem oSystem = new cSystem();
    oSystem.usethis();
}
```

Comment: Why bother with instantiating at all if your class and members seem to be static anyway

Comment: no it is not static. cSystem is a utility class. I stay away from static classes on web app's from a previous post.

Comment: I also use cSystem as one of my controllers and the .cs page uses them: using {myapp}.Controllers;  namespace {myapp}.Controllers
{
    public class cSystem
    {

Comment: I think in first case class just is not created, you should put it inside Page_Load or Page_Init anyway.

Comment: Static utility classes are fine in a web app. It's static *fields/properties* you should beware of.

Comment: Hint: I strongly suggest you don't prefix names with "o" and "c" and such. It's pretty obvious that `System` is a class, and that you're referring to it through the object `oSystem`. More importantly, most things are classes and objects, so it's no longer important to call them out.

Answer (score 2):

In most pages, there really wont be that big of a difference in practice.

The first example will create the instance when the `Page` is created. `oSystem` will be available for the entire lifetime of the page.

The second example will create the instance in the `Page_Load` event which doesn't happen until roughly the middle in the page lifecycle.

See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information on the page lifecycle.

If you wanted to use the instance earlier, in the `Page_Init` event for instance, then the former example wouldn't allocate the object earlier enough.

If your application needs to be high performance, requiring very efficient memory management, you would probably prefer the latter example. This example would allocate the memory closer to when it is being used so it wont be tying up resources longer than it needs to. That said, if you wanted efficient memory management, there are plenty of optimizations you could make.

So, in most pages, there isnt a practical difference.

Comment: Good info, I thinking about performance, and what you say makes sense. I looked at it as if it's used in many of the methods on that page that if I did it once it would be managed better, but it might be nicer to create it inside each method so that it is is managed better (I assume GC is the best way to have these cleaned up?).

Comment: Regarding the GC, yes. .NET has a great GC. In fact, I think it is quite difficult to get around the GC. I dont even know how to do it except for using COM objects or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Once scenario where creating a new instance on each method would a problem is if you need to keep object state outside the method scope. In this case, an instance per method would be wrong but I assume this is not the case for you.

Something else that might be important to consider is if that particular object is heavy to create or not.

In most of the cases is just a matter of taste as from perfomance point of view it will normally make no difference.

Proably the first scenario is more appropiate if you're creating the same instance many times and you could do the same work with a single and global instance. Just to avoid repeating the same instantiation line.

Answer (score 1):

- In the first case the class cSystem will be created just once for
  request.
- In the second case the class cSystem will be created twice when you click the submit  button, one in the `Page_Load` method and another in the `btnSubmit_Click` method.